# What's the meaning of unit of moment $\mathrm{N\cdot m}$? How do you explain it?

Tags: energy, work, torque, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I know the meaning of units with division like $\mathrm{m/s}$ or $\mathrm{m/s^2}$ etc. they make sense, like $2\ \mathrm{m/s}$ is like the car pass $2\ \mathrm m$ in $1$ second, you know what I mean?

But on the other hand $\mathrm{N\cdot m}$, it doesn't make sense like $\mathrm{m/s}$, because I don't know how to explain $2\ \mathrm{N\cdot m}$ for example.
So how to explain it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do units like joule \* seconds imply?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154451/)

Comment: yesssss @jonas thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moments, or torques, are like turning "forces". If you get a $1$ metre handle with one end attached to an axle, pushing with a $1$ newton at right angles at the other end gives a torque of $1\ \mathrm{ Nm}$. If you want $2\ \mathrm{ Nm}$ you can either double the length or you you can double the force. It is a little bit like area in that you can double the area by doubling either the length or the width. Or like getting distance by multiplying speed by time.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy

Comment: Incidentally it's also the unit of energy because one can consider it as a newton-meter per radian, kind of like an energy per angular distance, that way you can turn an object and do work doing so.