# Which physical entities equal "distance times time"?

Tags: time, units, distance

Are there useful physical quantities with dimensions of distance-time?

The background for this question is a differential equation which I try to make sense of:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095477/connections-between-the-solution-of-simple-ordinary-equation-normal-distributio

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question before on this site but I can't find an earlier version. Separately, a related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32096/

Comment: @DavidZ: I have also tried to find a similar question on this site before posting but haven't found one either.

Comment: Can you give us some background? Has something with dimensions of $LT$ cropped up in a calculation, or is this just curiousity?

Comment: @JohnRennie: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that the solution to $\dot{y}(t) = y(t)t$ is $y(t) = B \exp(-t^2/a^2)$, so what is the physical significance of the $y(t)t$ on the right hand side. Is that a fair summary?

Comment: @JohnRennie: Yes it is :-)

Comment: I'm thinking of a rental-car fee which not only charges both for time out and distance travelled but charges by the product of the two :-) .   Back to reality: if you've got an object whose position varies exponentially with time, I'd say it's just an "interesting observation" that you can represent it as  $y(t)*t$ .  Note that the $\lim(t\longrightarrow \infty)$ is kind of interesting!

Comment: vonjd, the equation in John's comments needs a dimensionful coefficient on the right hand side for the units to match the left hand side.  Assuming $y(t)$ had dimension L, then $\dot y(t)$ has dimension L/T while $y(t)t$ has dimension LT.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  easily handled by sticking a constant into the equation :-)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: Yes, I am thinking that $t$ is e.g. time, $x(t)$ (or $y(t)$) is distance and x' (or y') is velocity. I just changed the original equation because I think it gives a better intuition to use $t$ and $x(t)$.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, my point is that the right hand side does not have dimensions of LT.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: I see your point but how does the simplest ode $x'=x$ make sense then?

Comment: vonjd, consider the difference between the functions $y(x) = e^x$ and $v(t) = V_0 e^{-t/\tau}$ where, in the first case, y and x are numbers while in the second case, v and t are quantities.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: Well, I think the answer is what Carl has already mentioned: That you have a constant (which is in these cases $1$) that has a unit so that both sides are unitwise equal again.

Comment: vonjd, then if neither side has dimensions LT, why do you use this equation to motivate your question?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: Because I am interested in the $tx(t)$ part.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: In a way I can understand your frustration - on the other hand I still find it useful to think about e.g. $x'=x$ in terms of "velocity equals distance" which is also unitwise not correct (L/T != L) but gives an intuition why the solution is going to be exponential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the integral of position with respect to time is called the "Absement" which is a portmanteau of "absence" and "displacement." It seems the quantity is useful for measuring the net/average displacement, as you would divide this integral by the total time interval. It would also be useful for systems in which accumulated distance is dependent on a displacement and the length of a time of a given displacement. Examples include systems which expel power as a function of displacement, i.e. any kind of valve opening.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absement

Answer (score 0):

The quantity LxT is of interest because it is invariant between inertial reference frames, even as velocity approaches c.
LT = LoTo
Doc

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/428223)

Answer (score -3):

Distance is rate of change of position. Now let's play around with physics formulas:

**Acceleration** is velocity over time, or distance over time over time, d/t/t. Multiply by time, and you get:

**Velocity** is distance over time, or distance over time, d/t. Multiply by time, and you get:

**Displacement** is distance, or position over time, d. Multiply by time, and you get:

**Position** is distance into time, or position, dt. Multiply by time...

Please give credit if this turns out to be an amazing physics insight.

Comment: Distance and position are both quantities with dimensions of length.

Comment: Was the first premise that distance is rate of change of position correct? If that is true, then how is the rest of my logic wrong?

Comment: No, it was not.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake now. Distance is not a kind of motion, and hence can not have a time term in it.

Comment: However, I still insist that position and displacement do not have the same dimensions. Positions are points, not lengths, and are scaler rather than vector quantities.

Comment: That is true for alternative coordinate systems.  However, in Cartesian coordinates, physical space is often treated as an affine space, meaning that positions are given a vector space structure.  In this case, they have dimensions of length.

Comment: @AbdulMoizQureshi, to define a position, you must establish a coordinate system.  That coordinate system will have an origin.  Given that, it is always possible to associate position with displacement from that origin, even though said position is a point.