# Difference between - &

Tags: energy, work, terminology, notation, si-units

I’m taking Introductions to Physics book. In the book on the chapter “Physics & Mathematics” there was one question where we were supposed to find the magnitude of work done from given vectors Force & Displacement.

Using Dot product I successfully calculated the number part of Magnitude and wrote $Nm$ as unit.

Then I looked at the answer and it was written: $4.0 N-m$ or $4.0 J$.

I understand Joules but how is we have - instead of multiplication?

We can’t add difrent quantities, is that why we use - as multiplication operator. If yes why did we even needed it? What purpose does it justify?

Comment: Related: [What exactly is a kilogram-meter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32096/what-exactly-is-a-kilogram-meter)

Comment: Perhaps you should also fix the question title to be less ambiguous and more exact to your question. As it reads it doesn't even seem like it is talking about something physics related.

Comment: N-m is also a unit of torque, but torque is not work (aka energy).  Because of this, when I was teaching high school physics, I instructed my students to use "Joules" for work and "N-m" for torque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typesetting convention by that author or book publisher. I prefer your way of writing it, but you should not be surprised to see the other way used occasionally.

In the US, the N-m version is found more often in engineering texts (and usually in old ones rather than new ones) than in physics texts, but usage may vary around the world.

Of course you should also usually prefer to express energy or work in joules (J). If you see units of Nm or N-m, it usually denotes torque rather than energy or work.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, the point is that the "-" in "N-m" is a hyphen not a minus sign. It does not mean _Newtons minus metres_.